# PHP Database with files

Tags: php, database

For example, I have a file `.user1-info` and the content of the file is:

```
nick="Test"
password="403926033d001b5279df37cbbe5287b7c7c267fa"
join_date="1111111111"
rank="1"
```

How do I make an array with the content to use it as a database? For example:

`echo $usr_info['nick']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not doubt what your relationship is with the database.
To transform the data from a file as this format (I think that is one format .ini), you can use the native php function [parse_ini_file](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.parse-ini-file.php).

```
// Parse without sections
$ini_array = parse_ini_file(".user1-info");
print_r($ini_array);

/*
Array
(
    [nick] => "Test"
    [password] => "403926033d001b5279df37cbbe5287b7c7c267fa"
    [pasjoin_dateword] => "1111111111"
    [rank] => "1"
)
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can parse it as a `ini` file, because your format is very much like that, use [parse_ini_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) for that, like this:

```
$usr_info = parse_ini_file($file_path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to split each line by the equal sign.

```
$array = explode("=", $line, 1); // splits only by first equal sign
```

The first array element will be your key and the second will be very close to your value.